# Couldn't find User without an ID even when @user with params is created

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a Rails app with Devise.

Each User should be able to reply to a form which populates the model `Questionone`.
However, I keep getting `Couldn't find User without an ID`

What I did:
`rails generate scaffold Questionone first_question:text second_question:text user:references`

In my **User.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_many :questionones
end
```

In my **Questionone.rb** i have:

```
class Questionone < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

In my **questiones_controllers**

```
before_action :set_questionone, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @questionone = Questionone.new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    #If I use @user = current_user.id it works, but not sure if is right way
  end

  def create
    @questionone = Questionone.new(questionone_params)
    @questionone.user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @questionone.save
  end
  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_questionone
      @questionone = Questionone.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def questionone_params
      params.require(:questionone).permit(:user_id, :first_question, :second_question)
    end
end
```

If I use a `raise`, it tells me that `@user` is `nil`

**IF I USE @user = current_user.id** it works, but I am not sure it is the right way to go

Comment: Could you please show the full code of a controller? Or at least the `before_filter` `before_action` callbacks?

Comment: Added what I have on top of the controller

Comment: Could you show me your application controller callbacks as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of faulty logic there. Here is the answer:

```
  def new
    @questionone = Questionone.new
    @user = current_user
  end

  def create
    @questionone = Questionone.new(questionone_params)
    @questionone.user = current_user
    @questionone.save
  end
```

Also, you are not memoizing the Questionone (? weird name :D ), you should do it like this:

```
def set_questionone
  @questionone ||= Questionone.find(params[:id])
end
```

The longer answer:
I believe the user scope should be limited to the one that is currently login. If that's correct, then you are introducing a serious security problem in which anyone can create questions by pushing a `user_id` in the params.

Remove the `user_id` param entirely and use the `current_user` variable.